# How to pass value of a button to a string in order to use it later in java?

Tags: string, button, javafx

I'm writing a program requiring a button so as to get the location of a file (filepath). Now, after selecting the file, I want to pass the value to a string to which I can refer later on in the code below. Would you please tell me how to do it?

Here's the button

```
Label labelWatermark = new Label();
final String wmark = new String();
Button btnWmark = new Button("Watermark?");
btnWmark.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        FileChooser wmarkFile = new FileChooser();
        fileWmark =  wmarkFile.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        String filePathWmark = fileWmark.getAbsolutePath();
        labelWatermark.setText(filePathWmark);
        final String wmark = new String(filePathWmark);
    }
});

HBox hbBtnBrowse3 = new HBox(10);
hbBtnBrowse3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hbBtnBrowse3.getChildren().addAll(btnWmark, labelWatermark);
grid.add(hbBtnBrowse3, 1, 5);
```

I want to get the String `wmark` to be the filepath which I can use in this part below, specifically, the line containing `Image watermark_image = Image.getInstance(wmark)`:

```
try{
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
        String a = line;
        PdfReader Post_Survey = new PdfReader(pdf);
        int number_of_pages = Post_Survey.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(Post_Survey, new   
        FileOutputStream("sample - " + line + ".pdf"));
        int i = 0;
        Image watermark_image = Image.getInstance(wmark);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.WINANSI, 
                    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        watermark_image.setAbsolutePosition(20, 40);
        PdfContentByte add_watermark;
        PdfContentByte add_text;
        //start stamping!!
        while (i < number_of_pages) {
            i++;
            // watermark image
            add_watermark = stamp.getOverContent(i);
            add_watermark.addImage(watermark_image);
            // set where lines are    
            add_text = stamp.getOverContent(i);
            add_text.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
             ColumnText.showTextAligned(add_text,Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("This is the properties of blah blah and is solely used for " + line + " only!"), 20, 20, 0);
        }
        stamp.close();
        Post_Survey.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think that because the String `wmark` is enclosed within the button `btnWmark` so I cannot pass the string wmark out. So is there anyway we can refer to it for later use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you declare the StringBuilder `wmark` outside the `setonAction` of the button and append the value inside it ?

```
Label labelWatermark = new Label();
Button btnWmark = new Button("Watermark?");
final StringBuilder wmark = new StringBuilder();
btnWmark.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        FileChooser wmarkFile = new FileChooser();
        fileWmark =  wmarkFile.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        String filePathWmark = fileWmark.getAbsolutePath();
        labelWatermark.setText(filePathWmark);
        wmark.append(filePathWmark);
    }
});
```

And then later just use it

```
Image watermark_image = Image.getInstance(wmark.toString());
```

Comment: However, I think we have to comment out the line `final String wmark = new String();` don't you think?

Comment: Well, my bad, just remove that line.